# two errors when using gbm - object of type 'closure' is not subsettable - Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : #numeric 'envir' arg not of length one

Tags: r

I keep getting the two errors listed above. The first when I use my training data and the second when I use all of my data. Any help would be much appreciated. I have gone over all the questions here that are similar to this but I still don't understand how to resolve my problem. Here is an example of what my code and data look like:

```
 D1= c(1.8, 1.06, 0.46, 34.65, 1.8, 4.16, 2.55, 5.95, 13.63,3.72,1.38,14.94,17.08,3.39)
 D2 = c(1,1,2,6,1,3,1,6,6,2,1,3,1,5,3)
 D3= c(13,9, 211, 336, 2, 293.95, 211.95, 29, 0, 146, 0, 139.95, 12.04)
 D4 = c(m,m,m,m,m,m,m,m,m,m,m,f,m,m,f)
 D5 = c(0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1)
```

These are just the first 15 values of my dataset.

```
data = c(D1,D2, D3, D4, D5)
library('caTools')
set.seed(165)
splir = sample.split(data$HighUtPt, SplitRatio = 0.65)
train = subset(data, splir == TRUE)
test = subset(data, splir == FALSE)
require(gbm)
gbm_mod <-gbm(D5~ D1+D2+D3+D4, distribution = gaussian, data = train, shrinkage = 0.005, n.trees = 1000, bag.fraction = 0.5, cv.fold=50, interaction.depth=3) 

Error in eval(predvars, data, env) :  #numeric 'envir' arg not of length one
```

When I change the data argument to data = data, I get:
    'Error in d$name : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable'

when I use the main data set.

Comment: This example seems off. Did you really do `data = c(D1,D2, D3, D4, D5)`? Because that makes a single (character) vector, not a data.frame. And where is `data$HighUtPt` supposed to come from because you don't have anything labeled "HighUtPt" (same goes for "splir "). Please make sure your example is correct.

Comment: thanks. Yes it is from a csv file. I did not know how to attach the csv file so I copied the data above. Where you see data$HighUtPt it should be data$D5.   data = data.frame(D1,D2, D3, D4, D5)
library('caTools')
set.seed(165)
splir = sample.split(data$D5, SplitRatio = 0.65)
train = subset(data, splir == TRUE)
test = subset(data, splir == FALSE)
require(gbm)
gbm_mod <-gbm(D5~ D1+D2+D3+D4, distribution = gaussian, data = train, shrinkage = 0.005, n.trees = 1000, bag.fraction = 0.5, cv.fold=50, interaction.depth=3) 

Error in eval(predvars, data, env) :  #numeric 'envir' arg not of length one

Comment: Please update/edit the original question rather than putting the new/correct information in comments.